# PercentRelativeLayout with height wrap_content and children match_parent

Tags: android, layout, percentage

1. I am using a PercentRelativeLayout with multiple children inside of it
2. I want some of the children to have the same height as its parent
3. The parent's height should be "wrap_content"

Here is an oversimplified example, that does not work:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Label1 \n Line2 \n Line3"
        android:background="@color/green"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Label2 with\n two lines"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

What will be the simplest way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I did the following, please comment if this is ok to do (changing the children height in onMeasure)

```
public class PercentageRelativeLayout extends PercentRelativeLayout
{
public PercentageRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public PercentageRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public PercentageRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if(getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
        ArrayList<ViewGroup.LayoutParams> modifiedLayouts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
                child.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                modifiedLayouts.add(child.getLayoutParams());
            }
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if(modifiedLayouts.size() > 0) {
             int heightHint = getMeasuredHeight();

            if(heightHint > 0) {
                getLayoutParams().height = heightHint;
            }

            for (ViewGroup.LayoutParams params : modifiedLayouts)
                params.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            return;
        }
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
}
```

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, what you are doing is to change the inner views to wrap_content, recalculate the heights, assign the height to the parent, and change again the inner views to match_parent? Why dont you just change the layout inner views to wrap_content?

Comment: @Kazie - because I want all views to match the parent. For example if I have one TextView with 2 lines of text, others with 1 line. My code will make all text views height to be with 2 lines height.